# SSRS Expression in Text Field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to generate an expression that will return a value from one variable, depending on the value of another variable in the dataset.

Essentially I have two variables: flo_meas_id and meas_value.

I want the meas_value only to display if the flo_meas_id = 304221001'

Does anyone know if this is possible to accomplish in SSRS?

I have tried using the IFF statement but could not get it to work.

Comment: It sounds like the values are in a FIELD in the dataset, not a Variable in SSRS - is that right?

Comment: Yes, the variable is a field in the dataset in ssrs.

Answer (score 0):

The expression for the text box would use an IIF with the flo_meas_id comparison as the first argument, then the meas_vlaue field as the second argument for the value if true, and then NOTHING as the third argument for when the first argument is false)

```
=IIF(Fields!flo_meas_id.Value = "304221001", Fields!meas_vlaue.Value, NOTHING)
```